# How to change clearcase_albd account domain name and encrypted password using powershell script?

Tags: windows, powershell, encryption, scripting, clearcase

We are in the ClearCase windows domain migration phase. Now we migrated the domain but how to change clearcase_albd account domain name and encrypted password using power-shell script in user machine. I'm very new to powershell scripting.

Old Domain Name: Old_Domain
New Domain Name: New_Domain

Old Account: dragon
New Account: dragon_fire

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why use powershell? The SC command will do this nicely, and remotely.

Comment: Issue with batch script is we can't encrypt the password. By using power-shell we can achieve that.

Comment: Well,  SC lets you do it without actually being at the machine. But it doesn't help with the ClearCase admin group settings. You can use powershell to modify the registry. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/04/02/update-or-add-registry-key-value-with-powershell/